# get contact list with multiple phone numbers in windows phone 8 c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

In my windows phone application I want to get contact list of windows phone 8 and each contact have two or more phone numbers and I want to display contact name with phone numbers in my application and I am trying below:

```
xaml page:
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Name="ContactResultsLabel" Text="results are loading..." Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />

                <ListBox Name="ContactResultsData" ItemsSource="{Binding listOfContacts}" Height="200" Margin="24,0,0,0" >
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Name="ContactResultsName" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
            <Button x:Name="ButtonContacts"
                    Content="Get All Contacts"
                    FontSize="15"
                    Width="200"
                    Height="70"
                    Background="AliceBlue"
                    Foreground="Blue"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Click="ButtonContacts_Click"></Button>
            <Button x:Name="MergeContacts"
                    Content="Merge Contacts"
                    FontSize="15"
                    Width="200"
                    Height="70"
                    Background="AliceBlue"
                    Foreground="Blue"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    Click="MergeContacts_Click"></Button>
        </Grid>
```

And below is xaml.cs page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using GetContacts.Resources;
using Microsoft.Phone.UserData;

namespace GetContacts
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void ButtonContacts_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Contacts cons = new Contacts();
            cons.SearchCompleted += new EventHandler<ContactsSearchEventArgs>(Contacts_SearchCompleted);

            cons.SearchAsync(String.Empty, FilterKind.None, "Contacts Test #1");
        }

        void Contacts_SearchCompleted(object sender, ContactsSearchEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                List<CustomContact> listOfContact = new List<CustomContact>();
                foreach (var c in e.Results)
                {
                    CustomContact contact = new CustomContact();
                    contact.Name = c.DisplayName;
                    int count = c.PhoneNumbers.Count();
                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                    {
                        if (count > 0)
                        {
                            contact.Number[i] = c.PhoneNumbers.ElementAt(i).PhoneNumber.ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            contact.Number[i] = "";
                        }

                    }
                    listOfContact.Add(contact);
                }

                ContactResultsData.ItemsSource = listOfContact;
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {
                //No results
            }
            if (ContactResultsData.Items.Any())
            {
                ContactResultsLabel.Text = "results";
            }
            else
            {
                ContactResultsLabel.Text = "no results";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but when I am going into the class `CustomContact contact = new CustomContact();` its going me into the default contructor i.e empty. And below is my CustomContact class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using GetContacts.Resources;
using Microsoft.Phone.UserData;

namespace GetContacts
{
    class CustomContact
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string[] Number
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
       // public string Number1 { get; set; }

        public CustomContact()
        {
        }

        //CTOR that takes in a Contact object and extract the two fields we need (can add more fields)
        public CustomContact( Contact contact)
        {
            Name = contact.DisplayName;
            int count = contact.PhoneNumbers.Count();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                if (count > 0 && contact.PhoneNumbers.ElementAt(i).PhoneNumber != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(contact.PhoneNumbers.ElementAt(i).PhoneNumber))
                {
                    Number[i] = contact.PhoneNumbers.ElementAt(i).PhoneNumber.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                   Number[i] = "";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But its not working fine and not show me the list of contacts with multiple PhoneNumber and I am getting exception at this line `contact.Number[i] = c.PhoneNumbers.ElementAt(i).PhoneNumber.ToString();` and exception is `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` . I don't understand where I make mistake.
Kindly suggest me, waiting for reply.
Thanks.

Comment: line c.PhoneNumbers.ElementAt(i).PhoneNumber.ToString() in that count>0 but at some point Element is null so ElementAt(i) throw an exception

Answer (score 2):

you have to check the one more condition.

```
if(count>0 && c.PhoneNumbers.ElementAt(i)!=null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.PhoneNumbers.ElementAt(i).PhoneNumber))
{
contact.Number[i] = c.PhoneNumbers.ElementAt(i).PhoneNumber.ToString();
}
```

Comment: What if `c.PhoneNumbers.ElementAt(i).PhoneNumber== null` ?

Comment: @stackunderflow: its not going into the condition, it means `PhoneNumber` is not empty.

Comment: yes I do, but its not get me `PhoneNumber` into `contact.Number[i]`. Why?

Comment: I want to get `PhoneNumber` into the `contact.Number[i]`

Comment: do you have phonenumbers in c.PhoneNumbers?

Answer (score 0):

Do the same as Dhavel said and also check for this

`c.PhoneNumbers.ElementAt(i).PhoneNumber== null ?`

There might be some users who didn't have phone numbers

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help you.
in the CustomContact model Numbers Variable should be list of strings for multiple numbers of a contact, so CustomContact model should be:

```
 class CustomContact
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<string> Numbers { get; set; }


    public CustomContact()
    {
    }

    public CustomContact(string displayName, List<string> phoneNumbers)
    {
        this.Name = displayName;
        this.Numbers = phoneNumbers;
    }
}
```

and in GetContacts behindcode page define  numbers as string list:

```
 public partial class GetContacts : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    List<string> numbers = new List<string>();
    public GetContacts()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

.
.
.
and Contacts_SearchCompleted like below:

```
 void Contacts_SearchCompleted(object sender, ContactsSearchEventArgs e)
    {

            List<CustomContact> listOfContact = new List<CustomContact>();
            foreach (var c in e.Results)
            {

                CustomContact contact = new CustomContact();
                contact.Name = c.DisplayName;
                 numbers.Clear();
                int count = c.PhoneNumbers.Count();
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {

                    if (count > 0)
                    {

                    numbers.Add (c.PhoneNumbers.ElementAt(i).PhoneNumber.ToString());
                    }
                    contact.Numbers = numbers;

                }
                listOfContact.Add(contact);

            }

            ContactResultsData.ItemsSource = listOfContact;

        if (ContactResultsData.Items.Any())
        {
            ContactResultsLabel.Text = "results";
        }
        else
        {
            ContactResultsLabel.Text = "no results";
        }
    }
```

and in UI to show name and numbers use this code

```
  <ListBox Name="ContactResultsData" ItemsSource="{Binding listOfContacts}" Height="200">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Name="ContactResultsName" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                        <ListBox Name="ContactResultsNumbers" ItemsSource="{Binding Numbers}" Foreground="White" Height="50" Margin="24,0,0,0" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```